# How to overwrite a instance method of a base class in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

Sometimes, I just used an open source in my project, and want to overwrite some instance methods of a base class:

1. It's an open source project, I don't want to edit the source code of this project directly.
2. I can use `category` to overwrite, but it doesn't work If I want to use `super` in `category`.
3. I can't create a sub-class of it, since it's a base class. If I do it, I have to re-write all code about the base class to the new sub-class.

So, how to do it?

Comment: Look up method swizzling.

Comment: Exactly... thank you very much